# React Native fetch doesn't work in another fetch callback

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

If I call my api function from POINT 1, fetch method inside the api method works well. When I comment it out and call the function at POINT 2 fetch method **inside the addAccount()** doesn't work. There is no exception, no rejection, no request on Reactotron, even I can't find request over Charles Proxy. What is the difference and what I have to know to figure it out?

I tried with RN 0.55.2 and 0.57.5

```
// Auth.js typical react native component

import * as api from '../actions/api';

class Auth extends Component {

    // first triggered function
    loginAccount(){
        // api.addAccount();  // POINT 1 - this line works well if I uncomment
        fetch('https://domain-a.com/login/',{
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: {
                    'accept-language': 'en-US;q=1',
                    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                },
                body: encodeURIComponent(bodyParameters)
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json()
            }).then(({ status, invalid_credentials }) => {
                if(status == "ok"){
                    CookieManager.get('https://domain-a.com')
                        .then((cookies) => {
                            this.fetchAccountData(cookies);
                        })
            })

    }

    fetchAccountData(cookies){
        fetch('https://domain-a.com/'+cookies.user_id+'/info/',{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'cookie': cookies
                }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(({ user, status }) => {
            api.addAccount(); // POINT 2 - this line doesn't work
        });
    }
}


// api.js 
// I repleaced fetch code with document example just to be clearify

export const addAccount = () => {
    console.log("fetch begin"); // always works
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);  // won't works from point 2
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error); // never runs
    });
}
```

Comment: In which than statement have you written that method that is not running. Callback method only runs when the certain criteria met.

Comment: what is missing for last fetch method? console prints "fetch begin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your first .then statement in the addAccount() function is missing a return statement. responseJson would be undefined without a proper a 'return response.json()' statement. Also adding brackets for better semantic formatting.

```
export const addAccount = () => {
console.log("fetch begin"); // always works
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response); //test this response
    return response.json();
})
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);  // won't works from point 2
})
.catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error); // never runs
});
```

}

Comment: Editing with new suggestion

Comment: It works! After adding "return" and brackets. Still I'm confused. What is the difference and why works on point 1 but not point 2. Btw there is no return statement or brackets in sample code from official docs. Check the sample code in expo preview https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network

Comment: I agree, this is odd behavior. The sample code in the expo preview is a simpler example that uses shorthand and the compiler allowed us to get away with it. This can be a common issue in JavaScript - deeply nested functions are misinterpreted by the compiler sometimes when shorthand is used. We can often get away with skipping brackets and semi-colons and, in the sample code, return statements. For our use case, the compiler must have decided that it was time to break the function when it reached our response.json() as we were not explicit about what to do next.